# VBA Binding modification

Tags: vba, excel

I have tried to modify on this sample code given to me by [ron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604372/ron)

```
Sub test()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

my_url = "http://www.google.com"

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate my_url
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 530
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 400

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With

' Find the desired url and click
Set Results = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each itm In Results
    If itm.outerhtml = "B.A.C. VII" Then
        itm.Click

        Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Now i am not a fan of late binding so i am trying to modify the first two statements from

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

and replace them with

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer.Application
Set IE = New InternetExplorer.Application
```

However this doesn't work on my code even if i have the `Microsoft Internet Controls` and the the `Microsoft HTML Object Library` activated on references as you can see in the picture below.

WHY THAT?

[image]

Dear mehow

I have thought of that but it gives me error just look

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Set ie = new InternetExplorer
```

as `InternetExplorer` is the class name

[image]

Comment: Dear @mehow i have tried that but let me show you in my re-edited  question what it happened

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant right so `Set ie = new InternetExplorer`

Comment: ohhhhhh got dammit i must hit my head with a hammer of something!